# Sending multiple Merged Json Object to webservice and then consume them individually

Tags: c#, jquery, web-services, properties

Good Morning Guys!
My problem is simple and I need some instant solution. at Client, Side is Creating three different Objects of Json(obj1,obj2,obj3) that I need to send to Backend C# using web Service. As I know we are allowed to send only a single object to web Service so I merge all three independent JSON objects inside another shown below the FinalObject. now after sending the ajax Request can someone tell me who can I get these three objects as individual objects like Obj1, obj2, obj3. at the backend, I have three different Properties set of classes for these three objects. I'm receiving the object call as Object obj. thank you, guys.

> ```
>  Obj1 = {
>             'AlertName': inputs["Alert_Name"].value,
>             'Send_to_Admin': ($('#fullAdminUsers').is(':checked') == true?"Yes":"No"),
>             'Send_to_Employee': ($('#employee').is(':checked') == true ? "Yes" : "No"),
>             'Send_to_Manager': ($('#manager').is(':checked') == true ? "Yes" : "No"),
>             'Send_to_Others': ($('#otherSendTo').is(':checked') == true ? "Yes" : "No"),
>             'EmailSubject': inputs['EmailSubject'].value,
>             'CustomMessage': inputs['CustomMessage'].value,
>             
>         }
>     Obj2 = {
>              "EmployeeId": id,
>              "Employee_Name": emp_name,
>              "Alert_Group_Id": Is_allEmployees
>         }
>     Obj3 = {
>             newObject[key]["EventScope"] = EventScope;
>             newObject[key]["EventName"] = EventName;
>             newObject[key]["Eventtype"] = Eventtype;
>         }
>      FinalObject = {
>             'AlertData': Obj1,
>             'AlertGroup': Obj2,
>             'ERemainder': Obj3
>         }
> ```

Comment: You have a representation of FinalObject on the back end too

Comment: dear sir yes I do but it's of type object how can I assign this object's key to their respective class properties thank you that's all I wanna know. im getting final object in object combObj as param

Comment: It shouldn't be an `object`.. it should be a class with 3 properties of the types representing Obj1, Obj2 and Obj3

Comment: End of the day there is no rocket science here, if you're going to send a string, int and date representing a person's name, weight and birthday to an API then you make a class Person and you send them.  Then you send an address which is 3 strings.  Then if you want a person and their address you make another object that has a Person property and an Address property... You know how to make a person/address from simple props like strings and ints, making another class that is a Person/Address pair is just a logical extension of that process

Comment: yup i do but here properties were kind hybrid and had nested json objects with in which i need to map accordingto pre defiend classses etc

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can try that. Just convert this daha to JObject, then you can achieve to nested objects like data["AlertData"]. Then cast it whatever you want.

```
var obj1 = new { key1 = "value1" };
        var obj2 = new { key2 = "value2" };
        var obj3 = new { key1 = "value3" };

        var finalObj = new { AlertData = obj1, AlertGroup = obj2, ERemainder = obj3 };

        var jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(finalObj);

        var jData = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonData.ToString());

        var alertData = (dynamic)jData["AlertData"];
```

I used dynamic because i dont know what you want. You can use your real type instead of dynamic. You can achieve to Values like alertData.key in this scenario.

Comment: not working Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]' to type 'System.String'.'

Comment: doing JObject jobject =  JObject.Parse((string)combObj); but getting above error

Comment: I editted my answer. You just need last 2 lines.

Comment: Thanks Maan It Worked and now i can understand that we need to use dynamic to map the object to its destination. thanks

Comment: *we need to use dynamic* - no, you really dont